# How can i find all the duplicates in from an array without using ES6 features?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I am trying to do this without using es6 features but each time I end up using es6. Is there must be any way to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean ES6 features? What kind of duplicates are you talking about? Where is the array in question? What did you try to solve the problem and didn't work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which ES6 features you are talking about, but just using simple logic should be fairly straight forward (didn't test the code, just trying to explain a concept)

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
const found = []

arr.forEach(el => {
  if(found.includes(el)) {
    console.warn('Found duplicate: ', el)
return
}

found.push(el)
})
```

You can basically keep track of a list of elements that you already found, and do something when that element appears again.